# What does $I_{seg}$ in 3GPP TS 38.212 version 15.2.0 Release 15 represents?

Tags: segmentation

I'm working on 5G NR, whereby on reading **Code block segmentation and code block CRC attachment** given in **Subclause 5.2.1** of **3GPP TS 38.212 version 15.2.0 Release 15**.
[image]

What does $I_{seg}$ represent?

Answer (score 1):

$I_{\mbox{seg}} = 1$.

if payload $A>1013$ or $A\ge 360$ and $G>1077$. Divided two block segment
PUCCH $n_{\mbox{max}}=10$;
PDCCH $n_{\mbox{max}}=9$;